# Why can't use left join in indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that can't use left join in indexed view. but I don't understand why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q. Why can’t I use OUTER JOIN in an indexed view?
>
> A. Rows can logically disappear from an indexed view based on OUTER JOIN when you insert data into a base table. This makes
>   incrementally updating OUTER JOIN views relatively complex to
>   implement, and the performance of the implementation would be slower
>   than for views based on standard (INNER) JOIN.

Credits go to http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/25/sql-server-outer-join-in-indexed-view-question-to-readers/